# XAF/XPO How to integrate legacy database

Tags: c#, devexpress, xpo, xaf

We are experimenting with DevExpress XAF & XPO in order to use it for our further devlopment of an existing small business ERP system. We have a SQL database, where the existing tables must not be changed. What we are trying to do is to add new needed table properties only to a new tables that then should be "connected" to the old tables through object inheritance (`MapInheritanceType.OwnTable`).

For example:

We have a legacy tCustomer table. Now we add an XPO object tCustomerExtended like

```
public class tCustomerExtended : test.Module.BusinessObjects.db.tCustomer ...
```

The `tCustomerExtended` class then shall be extended with new properties and the `tCustomer` class remains unchanged (in order to be used by the old client application).

This works fine of course. A new table `tCustomerExtended` is generated with a primary key kCustomer (the key of the legacy table). Also XAF generates a UI as expected: The `tCustomerExtended` view is empty, since it shows the `tCustomerExtended` entries.

!!! But what we really want to achieve is to show all existing `tCustomer` entries in this view and the new properties of `tCustomerExtended`. The OnSaving method should then save the legacy properties to tCustomer and the new properties to tCustomerExtended. Also we have to generate a kCustomer key, since the old tCustomer table kCustomer PK has no Identity Specification.

At this moment I do not realize how to achieve this without changing the old `tCustomer` (what is absolutely not allowed).

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you create the subclass `tCustomerExtended`, XAF should generate detail views which *include* all the `tCustomer` properties too. I'm not sure why you are not seeing that behaviour.

Can't just add new columns to your old `tCustomer` table. So long as you don't change any existing columns, your old system should continue to work. Does your old system break if there are extra columns in the `tCustomer` table? If only minimal changes are allowed, you can just create an [`[Aggregated]`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/clsDevExpressXpoAggregatedAttributetopic) property with [`[ExpandObjectMembers]`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/clsDevExpressPersistentBaseExpandObjectMembersAttributetopic). This will add a single column to the old `tCustomers` table which will provide the link to all the extended properties.

If you really do need two tables with zero changes to `tCustomer`, then I think you will need to jump through some hoops to achieve exactly what you want. It's certainly possible, but the best answer will come from the [the DevExpress support center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) (as for all DevExpress-related questions). If you post a sample project there, the DevExpress team will quickly provide you with the best approach for your situation.